# Open links in Safari instead of relevant app

Tags: ios

I updated to iOS 14 and now tapping on Twitter links take me directly to the Twitter app instead of opening in Safari as they used to before. The links can be in an app like Messages or WhatsApp, or a share sheet ("Open in Safari"). I assume other services do this too, but I don't usually click on links related to other apps. Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: Remove the Twitter app?

Comment: I need the Twitter for certain purposes. I just don't want my links to be hijacked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get Safari to stop launching an app automatically?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105001/how-do-i-get-safari-to-stop-launching-an-app-automatically)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That sounds very similar, but I am not coming from Safari, so I cannot long-press.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain in a little more detail. Where exactly is a Twitter link? Stored in notes.app as text? In the native email app? In some other app?

Comment: It can be anywhere. For example, Messages app or a share sheet ("Open in Safari").